# Get Category name in Wordpress Walker Nav Menu

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, navigation, wp-nav-walker

I Write a Custom Nav Walker in My Wordpress Custom Child Theme.
I Need To Detect Current Category in my end_lvl Function. Is there Any Solution ?

```
function end_lvl(&$output, $depth=0, $args=null) {
        $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
        
        $divder_div_start = "<div class=\"megamenu-divder\">";
        $divder_div_end = "</div>";

    

          // Get 4 most recent product IDs in date descending order.
            $query = new WC_Product_Query( array(
              'limit' => 4,
              'orderby' => 'date',
              'order' => 'DESC',
              'return' => 'ids',
              'category' => array( 'md-o-poshak' ),
            ) );

            $topseller_img_tags = '';
            
            $products = $query->get_products();
              foreach($products as $p_id){
                $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $p_id ));
                $topseller_img_tags .= "\n<div><img src='$image[0]' width='150' height='150' /></div>";
              }


        $topseller_div_start = "<div class=\"top-seller-megamenu\">";
        $topseller_div_end = "</div>";

        if($depth > 0)
        {
            $output .= "$indent</ul>\n$indent\n$divder_div_start\n$divder_div_end\n$topseller_div_start\n$topseller_img_tags\n$topseller_div_end\n</section>\n";
        }
        else
        {
            $output .= "</ul>";
        }

      }
```

i need category name.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this:

```
$cat_name = '';
if (is_category()) {
    $category = get_queried_object();
    $cat_name = $category->name;
}
```